# Calling json in Swift with large indentation

Tags: json, swift, ios8

I have a JSON data being called in async my has problem is, how does one call the title from item:1

```
{
"rss": {
    "channel": {
        "atom:link": "",
        "title": "The Local",
        "link": "http://www.thelocal.se/",
        "description": "Sweden's news in English",
        "language": "en-us",
        "managingEditor": "TheLocal",
        "webMaster": "TheLocal",
        "generator": "TheLocal RSS Feed Generator",
        "item:0": {
            "title": "Knausgård savages the 'Cyclops' Swedes",
            "description": "Norwegian literary star Karl Ove Knausgård has launched an extraordinary attack on the Swedes, damning them as a race of narrow-minded “cyclops” who cannot tolerate ambiguity, have no understanding of literature, and are “full of hate and fear”.",
            "link": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/knausgrd-savages-the-cyclops-swedes",
            "pubDate": "2015-05-20 15:25:25",
            "guid": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/knausgrd-savages-the-cyclops-swedes"
        },
        "item:1": {
            "title": "Migration Board worker took bribes for passports",
            "description": "A court in Malmö has jailed a former Migration Board worker and his accomplice for taking bribes in exchange for residence permits and passports for asylum seekers desperate to stay in Sweden.",
            "link": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/two-found-guilty-in-migration-board-bribery-case",
            "pubDate": "2015-05-20 12:32:46",
            "guid": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/two-found-guilty-in-migration-board-bribery-case"
        },
        "item:2": {
            "title": "Two million Swedes design 'house of clicks'",
            "description": "A team of award-winning architects have joined forces with two million Swedes to design the country’s most sought-after home.",
            "link": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/two-million-swedes-design-dream-house-of-clicks",
            "pubDate": "2015-05-20 12:01:35",
            "guid": "http://www.thelocal.se/20150520/two-million-swedes-design-dream-house-of-clicks"
        },
```

The Code I have now at the moment that wont compile is:

```
if var jsonArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as? Array<NSDictionary> {

                            println("jsonArray: \(jsonArray)")
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                                for var i:Int = 0; i < jsonArray.count; i++ {

                                    var title:String = jsonArray["rss"]["item:\(i)"].valueForKey("title") as String
```

So what I was thinking was that I would call each indentation as shown above but now its saying AnyObject? does not have a member named valueForKey.

I am thinking that its my format to calling the information from the array dictionary.

Could someone help me as trying to describe this issue to google has stumped me as it is difficult to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your JSON is not an `Array` so cast it to `NSDictionary` (which has `valueForKeyPath` method) at the end of serialization method.
Then just use

```
if let item1title = json?.valueForKeyPath("rss.channel.item:1.title") {
    //here you are ready tu use it
}
```

Comment: What if the item had no number so son?.valueForKeyPath("rss.channel.item.title") how would I deal with 5 with the tag item?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. Can you ask one more time but more accurate?

Comment: If you take the above example but instead of having item:N for indexing. What about the scenario if each is sorted by "item" tag, how would I deal with lack of indexing, Dictionary those not provide indexing.

Comment: Are you asking what if you'll have n items? Here's problem with your JSON - the "items" sholud be an array: `"items":[{item1obj},{item2obj},..,{item3obj}]"`